# find strings containing space using full text search

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, sql-server-2014

Let's say we have a column with this value:

```
bla dibla
```

which (CONTAINS?) search expression can I use to find the above entry using this search string:

```
bladibla
```

Comment: select  columnname from table where replace(columnname,' ','')  like '%bladibla%'.Try like this

Comment: That not a full text search or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it's impossible to search such strings with full text search, because MSSQL analyze rows and gets "words" (tokens) from strings. So, if you have value `bla dibla`, MSSQL will split it to two words `bla` and `dibla`.
To solve your problem, you can do this:

1. Add persisted computed column with formula `(replace([Value],' ',''))`
2. Add full text index on this column
3. And use search on computed column

---

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ValueTrimed]  AS (replace([Value],' ','')) PERSISTED,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([Id] ASC)

INSERT INTO TestTable
(Value)
Values
('bla dibla')

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[TestTable] as tt
where CONTAINS (tt.ValueTrimed, 'bladibla')

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[TestTable] as tt
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE([dbo].[TestTable], ValueTrimed, 'bladibla') AS KEY_TBL ON tt.Id = KEY_TBL.[KEY];
```

Comment: Thanks makes sense. Is there no fuzzy type of search potentially involving FREETEXT.

Comment: @csetzkorn i spend many time tuning msssql full text search, and it's very difficult to do something more complex than simple `CONTAINS` and masked search. I always had to use some hacks or additional calculations, columns, tables and so on. So, fo real complex text search you should better use something like ElasticSearch. But, simple solution can be achieved in MSSQL.

Comment: Thanks. Any opinions on Mongo db for 'full text search'?

Comment: @csetzkorn has no experience with MongoDB. We use ElasticSearch about 5 years and it's really good. But, it's only my option.

Comment: Ok thanks. will look into it. btw your suggestion works great.

Comment: @csetzkorn glad to help!